# Identity Server 4 CORS errors when trying to access via Angular 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cors, identityserver4

I have set up my identity server and got it working using postman.
Now I want to get my client application to connect, but I keep getting CORS issues.

I have set my **Startup** class to look like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private readonly ILogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService> _logger;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>();

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(m =>
            m.AddPolicy("localhost", o => o.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200")));
        services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
        services.Configure<Config>(Configuration.GetSection("Options"));

        var cors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(_logger) {AllowAll = true};
        var buildServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var config = buildServiceProvider.GetService<IOptions<Config>>();

        services.AddTransient(typeof(IGenericService<>), typeof(GenericService<>));
        services.AddSingleton<ICorsPolicyService>(cors);

        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.Value.ConnectionString));
        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        IdentityServerExtensions.AddIdentityServer(services);
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info {Title = "Identity Server", Version = "v1"});
            //c.OperationFilter<CheckAuthorizeOperationFilter>();
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
            {
                Type = "oauth2",
                Flow = "implicit",
                AuthorizationUrl = $"{config.Value.IdentityServerBaseUrl}connect/authorize",
                TokenUrl = $"{config.Value.IdentityServerBaseUrl}connect/token",
                Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Sxp", "Identity Server"}}
            });
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.SeedIdentityServerDatabase();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors("localhost");
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Identity Server v1");
            c.OAuthClientId("swagger");
            c.OAuthAppName("Swagger Api UI");
        });
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

and I seeded my database with a client with all allowed origins like this:

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ro.client",
    ClientName = "Resource Owner Client",
    AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string>{"http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200"},
    AllowedGrantTypes =
    {
        GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword
    },
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = {"Sxp"}
},
```

but this does not appear to be working.
Am I missing something else?

---

As a test, I added a controller with no Authorize attribute and called it from my Angular application like this:

```
return this.http.get(`${environment.identityServerUrl}/users`).pipe(map(response => console.log(response)));
```

And that worked with no issues.
So it appears there is a problem with CORS for IdentityServer

Comment: Does it work if you use the actual origin and not *?

Comment: You cannot user "allow any origin"

Comment: I have tried with actual origins too and it works in both fiddler and postman (although I know postman doesn't care about CORS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have forgotten about Methods and Header

```
services.AddCors(m => m.AddPolicy("localhost", o =>
    o.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "https://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyMethod() // mising part
        .AllowAnyHeader() // mising part
    ));
```

Although in your case - without `AllowAnyMethod` should work too.